# Terminology to Use

Tags: terminology, epidemiology, causality

Should you say a factor is associated with a disease or disease risk? For example, which is better to say:

1. Smoking is associated with lung cancer
2. Smoking is associated with lung cancer risk

Answer (score 1):

Saying 'smoking is associated with lung cancer' is more appropriate since your outcome is likely to have been occurrence or onset of lung cancer. If you said 'smoking is associated with first lung cancer diagnosis' this would be even more clear since it rules out recurrence, etc.

Many people do use statements of the second type, but since you use the tag 'causal inference' I'm assuming you are interested in causal inference, for which the key is to be as clear as possible about the effects you are assessing. The second statement is less clear to me, since it could suggest an outcome of lung cancer or an outcome of (high) lung cancer risk score, such as from a disease risk model.

Of course, when presenting actual results, you are going to need to say something even more specific. For example: "ever smoking was associated with a 1.3-fold increase in lung cancer diagnosis compared to individuals who never smoked, among a certain population, over the follow-up period, controlling for age, etc."